# Perl -- regex issue

Tags: regex, string, perl, file

I have the following code to get a substring inside an string, I'm using regular expressions but they seem not to work properly. How can I do it?

I have this string:

```
vlex.es/jurisdictions/ES/search?textolibre=transacciones+banco+de+bogota&translated_textolibre=,300,220,00:00:38,2,0.00%,38.67%,â‚¬0.00
```

and I want to get this substring:

```
transacciones+banco+de+bogota
```

**The code:**

```
open my $info, $myfile or die "Could not open $myfile: $!";

while (my $line = <$info>) {
    if ($line =~ m/textolibre=/) {
        my $line =~ m/textolibre=(.*?)&translated/g;
        print $1;
    }

    last if $. == 3521239;
}

close $info;
```

**The errors:**

```
Use of uninitialized value $line in pattern match (m//) at classifier.pl line 10, <$info> line 20007.
Use of uninitialized value $1 in print at classifier.pl line 11, <$info> line 20007.
```

Comment: What is not working exactly ? The regex matches the piece you want correctly !!

Comment: I see you are back at your old tricks, changing the details of the question randomly to disqualify the answers you are given (such as adding errors afterwards, or changing `print $line` to `print $1`). That sort of behaviour is certainly not appreciated by people trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second declaration of `$line` is erroneous, drop `my`:

```
$line =~ m/textolibre=(.*?)&translated/g;
```

Comment: why the downvote? the original version of the question contained `print $line`.

Comment: @marcotiz: remove `my`from `my $line =~ m/textolibre=(.*?)&translated/g;`- you are redefining a variable here.

Answer (score 5):

You are using the wrong tool for the job. You can use the [`URI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI) module and its [`URI::QueryParam`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI::QueryParam) module to extract the parameters:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use URI;
use URI::QueryParam;

my $str = "ivlex.es/jurisdictions/ES/search?textolibre=transacciones+banco+de+bogota&translated_textolibre=,300,220,00:00:38,2,0.00%,38.67%,0.00";

my $u = URI->new($str); 
print $u->query_param('textolibre');
```

**Output:**

```
transacciones banco de bogota
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I've found the answer. At line 10 `my $line =~ m/textolibre=(.*?)&translated/g;` I'm declaring the same variable two times so that's why throws the errors.
Thanks!