# Finding a text in a string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string as below:

```
$var = "ABC/type.xml/BYB?not=1234&at=6789&xyz&LMN";
```

I want to get the not and at values.. How can work with it??

Comment: What have you researched or tried?

Comment: I have tried to split the variable using '?' first which gives us a variable with var2 ="not=1234&at=6789&xyz&LMN"

Comment: Then I am splitting using & . It increases my lines of code.. is there any other way??

Comment: I'm no expert, but i found this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363899/how-to-extract-values-from-a-string-in-javascript][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363899/how-to-extract-values-from-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18355942/725418

Answer (score 5):

You can, and probably should, use a proper module that can parse this string properly, such as [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) and [`URI::QueryParam`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::QueryParam):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use URI;
use URI::QueryParam;

my $str = "ABC/type.xml/BYB?not=1234&at=6789&xyz&LMN";
my $url = URI->new($str);
my $not = $url->query_param('not');
my $at  = $url->query_param('at');
print Dumper $not, $at;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = '1234';
$VAR2 = '6789';
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing is probably to pull all the values out into a hash in a single shot:

```
my $var = "ABC/type.xml/BYB?not=1234&at=6789&xyz&LMN";

my %values = $var =~ /(\w+)(?:=(.*?))?(?:&|\Z)/g;
```

After this, you  have

```
  DB<5> x \%values
0  HASH(0x7fa133018f98)
   'LMN' => undef
   'at' => 6789
   'not' => 1234
   'xyz' => undef
```

Comment: Didn't know of the groups into hash capability. Interesting line.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using regex to extract the matches:

```
my $var = "ABC/type.xml/BYB?not=1234&at=6789&xyz&LMN";

$var=~/not=(.*?)&/;
my $a=$1;
$var=~/at=(.*?)&/;
my $b=$1;

say $a,",",$b;
```

Output:

```
1234,6789
```

Comment: Wow much easier..  Thanx.. :)

Comment: One point to consider is to put `\b` before the keys you are trying to match so you don't accidentally match `cat=4&` when you're looking for `at`.  So you'd say `$var=~/\bat=(.*?)&/;`